# How to manually mapping String to postgresql text instead of just varchar(254)?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I use slick2+postgresql 9.3+playframework 2

My data model is:

```
class Page(tag:Tag) extends Table[(Long,Long, String,String,String, Option[Long], Option[Long])](tag, "Page"){
  def id=column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def subId=column[Long]("subject")
  def title=column[String]("Title", O.NotNull)
  def describe=column[String]("Describe")
  def profile=column[String]("Profile")
  def icon=column[Long]("icon")
  def resId=column[Long]("Picture")
  def * = (id, subId,title, describe, profile,icon.?, resId.?)
  def page_sub=foreignKey("PA_SU_FK", subId, subject)(_.id)
  def page_res=foreignKey("PA_RE_FK", resId, resource)(_.id)

}
```

the problem is the column describe is String and will be mapping as varchar(254) in database. But actually, this column may very very long, I mean it may 1000-3000 characters.
how to manually mapping it to text in Datamodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for `PostgreSQL`:

```
def profile=column[String]("Profile",  O.DBType("TEXT"))
```

Or you could build a custom `TypeMapper`, I never built one but there are a lot of posts around, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818827/customer-type-mapper-for-slick-sql) SO question or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaquery/4Ns_J_8wbqQ/0SGiJL4O8A8J) question.

Hope it helps.