# Joda-Date Mapper for Slick - MappedColumnTyoe

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

My problem is very close to this question, but my error is different.

[Customer Type Mapper for Slick SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818827/customer-type-mapper-for-slick-sql)

This is my utility class where JDATE and the Mapper is defined

```
package org.mydomain.utils
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.sql.Date
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.sql.Timestamp

sealed trait JDATE

object DateUtils {

  implicit def jdateColumnType  =
      MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
        dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
        ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
  )
}
```

The domain object User.scala is as follows

```
case class UserRow(id: Long, birthday: JDATE)

class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "USER") {
def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
def birthday = column[JDATE]("BIRTHDAY")

def * = (id, birthday) <> (UserRow.tupled, UserRow.unapply)
}
```

Error:
not enough arguments for method column: (implicit tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[org.mydomain.utils.JDATE])scala.slick.lifted.Column[org.mydomain.utils.JDATE]. Unspecified value parameter tm.

How to pass the tm here ? Apologies for this noob question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You don't need `JDATE` - you don't actually want to use it anywhere, what you *want* is to be able to translate between `DateTime` and `Timestamp` instances.  Use `DateTime` for the `column` type instead (e. g. `column[DateTime]("BIRTHDAY")` rather than `column[JDATE]("BIRTHDAY")`)
2. You never actually import your implicit `DateTime <> Timestamp` converter, so it is never picked up by Slick's `column`.  Either:

   ```
   // Import the implicit in the constructor
   class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "USER") {
     import org.mydomain.utils.DateUtils.jdateColumnType
     // Your code here
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   // Explicitly pass the implicit converter in yourself
   class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "USER") {
     // ... snip ...
     def birthday = column[DateTime]("BIRTHDAY")(DateUtils.jdateColumnType)
     // ... snip ...
   }
   ```

   or (best option), create your own driver by extending the `MySql` driver with your custom implicit in a trait:

   ```
   package org.mydomain.db

   import scala.slick.driver.{MySqlDriver, JdbcDriver}

   trait DateUtils {
     implicit def jdateColumnType  =
         MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
           dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
           ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
     )
   }

   trait CustomMySqlDriver extends JdbcDriver with MySqlDriver with DateUtils

   object CustomMySqlDriver extends CustomMySqlDriver
   ```

   and you can then use it like this:

   ```
   import org.mydomain.db.CustomMySqlDriver.simple._

   class User(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow](tag, "USER") {
     // ... snip ...
     def birthday = column[DateTime]("BIRTHDAY")
     // ... snip ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went with the option of extending the MySQL Driver. I dont think my User object is seeing the mapping for some reason. 
[error] /Users/andy/git2/src/main/scala/org/mydomain/model/User.scala:105: could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[org.joda.time.DateTime]
[error]   def birthday = column[DateTime]("BIRTHDAY")