# Printing interpolated SQL query in Slick

Tags: scala, jdbc, prepared-statement, slick, slick-2.0

I am trying to print an interpolated Slick2 SQL statement for debugging and all I get is the one with question marks e.g.

```
def query(name: String) = sql"SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE name = $name".as[Int]
println(query("Bob").getStatement)
```

The above prints this:

```
SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE name = ?
```

How can I make it print this:

```
SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE name = 'Bob'
```

Note: This questions is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434286/view-sql-query-in-slick)

Comment: The problem that you are trying to solve is not strictly slick related: slick creates prepared statements at the JDBC level and those are printed in that way. I suspect that you should look into how to print JDBC prepared statements rather than focusing your attention on slick. I am not sure that there is a way to do that in JDBC though.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to add the following to your application.conf

```
logger.scala.slick.session=DEBUG
```

This should show compiled query strings in the console.

Comment: I have a Play app. I added it to both my application.conf and I added it to my logger.xml: `<logger name="scala.slick.session" level="INFO"/>` But, I don't see it...

Comment: What happens when you change to log level to "DEBUG" in logger.xml?

Comment: Same. I downgraded to DEBUG too. Nothing. I am on Slick 2.0 + Play 2.2

Comment: Can you edit to show what your application.conf and logger.xml looks like? I'm sure you're just one param off from getting the logs. Meanwhile, try `<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>`

Answer (score 3):

From the slick [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql.html): "You can use #$ instead of $ to get the literal value inserted directly into the query".

```
//note the '#'
def query(name : String) = sql"SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE name = '#$name'".as[Int]
```

Comment: No, I don't want `#$` as that is meant to splice in parts of the SQL statement itself (e.g. table names etc). This would produce incorrect SQL since it would do `where name=Bob` instead of `where name='Bob'`. I want `$` to bind variables...

Comment: This also won't work for non primitives e.g:

`def query(birthdate : LocalDate) = sql"SELECT MAX(age) FROM users WHERE birthday > $birthdate".as[Int]`

Here if I have the correct implicit in scope, it will convert into the correct SQL bind variable. If I use `#$`, it would just put the `.toString` of `LocalDate` which I may not want.

Comment: I added the single quotes into the query to produce proper sql.  I don't know what you would want the println to show for "non-primitives" since those are the only types of values that can go into an sql query...

Comment: If you want non-default behavior then why not construct the string first and then apply the sql function to the constructed string?  Why have sql act as your regular expression evaluator?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sql act as your regular expression evaluator". Slick let's you bind custom classes using the [type mapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818827/customer-type-mapper-for-slick-sql) which can only be correctly binded using `$` interpolator and not the `#$` one.